# How to read and Write multiple files using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a array I have filenames; I want to  first read one file and perform some operation then store result in a separate file. Then read 2nd file, perform operation again and save result in new 2nd file. Do the same procedure for all files. Below I have written code to read and write files.

TextReader.js

```js
var fs = require('fs');
const readline= require('readline');
var headerIndex = [];
var isFirstLine = true;
var finalList = [];


module.exports={
    readTextFile: (filename)=>{

        console.log('inside textreader')

        readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(`./s3/${filename}`)

        }).on('line', function(line) {

            console.log(line);
            console.log("-----------------------------");
                
            if (isFirstLine) {
                headerIndex = line.split('|');
            }
            else if (!isFirstLine){
                let rowValues = line.split('|');
                let valueIndex = 0;
                var singlePerson = {};
                headerIndex.forEach(currentval => {
                        
                    singlePerson[currentval] = rowValues[valueIndex];
                    valueIndex++;
                });
                finalList.push(singlePerson);
            }
            isFirstLine = false;
        
        }).on('close',function(){
            //console.log(finalList);

            var data='';
            
            var header= "Employee ID"+'\t'+headerIndex[0]+'\t'+headerIndex[2]+'\t'+headerIndex[1]+'\t'+headerIndex[4]
            +'\t'+headerIndex[3]+'\t'+headerIndex[5]+'\n';
    
            for (var i = 0; i < finalList.length; i++) {
    
                function split(name){
                  
                  var conv=name.split(' ');
                  var result=[conv.slice(0, -1).join(' '),conv.slice(-1)[0]].join(conv.length < 2 ? '' : ','); 
                  return result;
                }
                split(finalList[i].UserName);
          
              data=data+finalList[i].LoginID+'\t'+split(finalList[i].UserName)+'\t'+finalList[i].Email+'\t'
              +finalList[i].LoginID+'\t'+'A&G Professional'+'\t'+finalList[i].Title+'\t'+finalList[i].State+'\n';
              
            }
            var newFilename= filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."))
            var alldata= header + data;
            //console.log(alldata)
            fs.appendFile(`./s3/${filename}.xlsx`,alldata, (err) => {
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log('File created');
            });

        });
    }
    
}
```

I am calling readTextFile(); from another file.

demo.js

```js
const { readTextFile } = require("./textReader");

var array=['UserRoleDetails_12102021063206.txt',
'UserRoleDetails_12102021064706 (1).txt',
'UserRoleDetails_12102021064706.txt',
'UserRoleDetails_12102021070206.txt']

array.forEach(function(currentItem){
    readTextFile(currentItem);
})
```

The problem i am facing is that all files are processed at the same time and all the datas of all files are stored together.

Answer (score 0):

first, this node js is not work in sequential as you mention here

and second,  **array.forEach** is not useful here to do the sequential operation

you need to use

```
const { readTextFile } = require("./textReader");

var array=['UserRoleDetails_12102021063206.txt',
         'UserRoleDetails_12102021064706 (1).txt',
         'UserRoleDetails_12102021064706.txt',
         'UserRoleDetails_12102021070206.txt']

for (const element of array) {
    readTextFile(currentItem);
}
```

NOTE:- **readTextFile(currentItem)** your this function is not async so maybe you need to make it async

if you are not clear then raise your hand